# "sudo apt update" gives GPG error, and "sudo apt-key adv" (even though successful) didn't resolve the issue

Tags: ubuntu, ros, apt, ros2

"sudo apt update" gives GPG error on "packages.ros.org", and "sudo apt-key adv" (even though successful) didn't resolve the issue. please find attached the image of the same.
[image]

Comment: Did you add the GPG Keys to apt? [See also](https://answers.ros.org/question/410123/ubuntu-2204-ros2-humble-installing-error-gpg-libc-bin/)

Comment: @Pieterjan Thanks. this resolved this error. you have no idea how much this means. thank you so much.

Comment: The `sources.list` file by default already contains some entries with the default debian registries. The GPG keys for these are too registered by default. When adding other debian archives to `sources.list`, you need to register the corresponding GPG keys before you can run `sudo apt-get update`. Then these packages will become available for installation